# Java's varying available heap size

Tags: java, heap-memory

I just found out that there are some libraries to compute the shallow size of a java object, so I thought I can also write this in a very simple way. Here is what I tried.

1. Start the program with some `Xmx` say `A`
2. Create objects of type whose size you want to calculate (say type `T`) and store them in a list so that GC shouldn't clean them up.
3. When we hit OOM, let the code handle it and empty the list.
4. Now check the number of the objects of type `T` we allocated. Let this be `n`
5. Do a binary search to find out the delta inorder to successfully allocate `n+1` objects.

Here is the code, I tried out

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] a) {
        ArrayList<Integer> l = new ArrayList<>();
        int i=0;
        try {
            while(true) {
                l.add(new Integer(1));
                i++;
            }
        } catch(Throwable e) {
        } finally {
            l.clear();
            System.out.println(i + "");
        }
    }
}
```

But I noticed that the number of objects allocated in each run for a same `Xmx` was varying. Why is this? Is there anything inside JVM randomized?

Comment: Wouldn't the number of allocated objects also very depending on the aggergate of other variables since they are all stored in the heap?  You have an array list and int also taking up space.  (Just a curious thought).  Also, the way I understand it, the JVM uses available resources that are distributed by the OS.  If that is the case, it is possible to have a changing heap.

Comment: @JoshThrasher Shouldn't that be a constant for each run?

Comment: That's true.

I wonder if you ran a bunch of stuff in the background if you would get significantly smaller results.  If so, that would support the idea that JVM allocates available resources only.

Comment: No my laptop has plenty of memory available all the time (~50%)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But I noticed that the number of objects allocated in each run for a same Xmx was varying. Why is this?

Some events in the JVM are non-deterministic, and this can effect garbage collector behavior.

But there could be factors in play that are resulting in variable numbers of (your) objects being created before you fill up the heap.  These include:

- Not all of the objects in the heap will be the `ArrayList` and `Integer` objects that you are explicitly creating.  There will be `Object[]` objects that get created when you resize the `ArrayList`, various objects generated by your `println` calls ... and other things that happen under the hood.
- Heap resizing behavior.  The heap is not immediately sized to -Xmx size.  The JVM typically starts with a smaller heap size and expands it on demand.  By the time you get an OOME, the JVM has most likely expanded the heap to the max permitted, but the sequence of expansions is potentially sensitive to ... various factors including some that may be non-deterministic.
- Heap generations.  A typical Java GC uses an old space and a new space.  The old space contains long-lived objects.  New objects are allocated into the new space ... unless they are very large.  The actual distribution of the objects can affect when the GC runs occur, and when JVM is going to decide that the heap is full.
- JIT compilation.  At certain points in the execution of your application, the JVM will (typically) decide to JIT compile your code.  When this happens, extra objects get allocated.

---

> Is there anything inside JVM randomized?

It is unlikely to be explicit randomization affecting this benchmark.  There is sufficient non-determinism at various levels (i.e. in the hardware, the OS and the JVM) to explain the inconsistent results you are seeing.

---

In short: I wouldn't expect your benchmark to give consistent results for the number of objects that can be created.